# *Python- porque meu código está me dando uma informação que não pedi?

Tags: python, lógica

deveria me mostrar apenas o valor do combustivel que solicitei, mas ele me mostra o valor tanto de gasolina quanto de alcool, não importa se eu digitar D ou A:

```
tipo_comb = input('Digite [G} para gasolina \nE [A] para alcool: ')
quantidade = float(input('Quantidade desejada: '))
cadastro = input('Digite [C] se possuir cadastro \nDigite [D] se não possuir cadastro: ')
gasolina = float(4.34*quantidade)
alcool = float(3.79*quantidade)
#não clientes e gasolina
if cadastro == 'D' or cadastro == 'd' and quantidade <= 20:
    print('você comprou {} litros, sem desconto seriam: {:.3f} reais \nO valor total com desconto é de {:.3f} reais'.format(
        quantidade,gasolina, (gasolina - gasolina*0.03)))
elif cadastro == 'D' or 'd' and quantidade >20 and tipo_comb == 'G' or 'g':
    print('você comprou {} litros, sem desconto seriam: {:.3f} reais \nO valor total com desconto é de {:.3f} reais'.format(
        quantidade, gasolina, (gasolina - gasolina * 0.05)))

#não clientes e alcool
if cadastro == 'C' or 'c' and quantidade <= 20:
    print('você comprou {} litros, sem desconto seriam: {:.3f} reais \nO valor total com desconto é de {:.3f} reais'.format(
            quantidade, alcool, (alcool - alcool* 0.03)))
elif cadastro == 'C' or 'c' and quantidade >20:
    print('você comprou {} litros, sem desconto seriam: {:.3f} reais \nO valor total com desconto é de {:.3f} reais'.format(
            quantidade, alcool, (alcool - alcool * 0.05)))
```

Comment: Apenas o seu primeiro if está correto. Os outros 3 fazem algo como `'D' or 'd'` e isso não faz sentido. Você precisa comparar com cada valor separadamente ou fazer `cadastro in ['D', 'd']`

Comment: poxa não tinha reparado, agora funcionou, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nas condicionais depois da linha `#não clientes e alcool` faltou a condição de que `(tipo_comb == 'A' or tipo_comb == 'a')`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tambem converter a entrada do usuario para um tipo de letra e verificar apenas uma

```
cadastro = str(input('Digite [C] se possuir cadastro \nDigite [D] se não possuir 
cadastro: ')).upper()
```

Ai nas verificações você veriica apenas com letra maiuscula.

```
if cadastro == 'D' and quantidade <= 20:
elif cadastro == 'D'and quantidade >20 and tipo_comb == 'G':#Considerando que fez a 
mesma coisa na entrado de tipo_comb.
```

Assim fica mais fácil porque voce não precisa criar listas para verifica as entradas do usuario, convertendo para um padrão não importa se ele digitar maiuscula ou minuscula vai ser sempre comparado com maiuscula.

Answer (score 0):

Nas condições if voçê especificou que o código seria executado se o usuário era ou não cliente , mas não especificou que o 1º if só seria executado para casolina e o 2º para o alcool.
O código corrigido ficaria assim :

```
tipo_comb = input('Digite [G} para gasolina \nE [A] para alcool: ')
quantidade = float(input('Quantidade desejada: '))
cadastro = input('Digite [C] se possuir cadastro \nDigite [D] se não possuir cadastro: ')
gasolina = float(4.34*quantidade)
alcool = float(3.79*quantidade)
#não clientes e gasolina
if cadastro == 'D' or cadastro == 'd' and quantidade <= 20 and tipo_comb == "G" or tipo_comb == "g" :
    print('você comprou {} litros, sem desconto seriam: {:.3f} reais \nO valor total com desconto é de {:.3f} reais'.format(
        quantidade,gasolina, (gasolina - gasolina*0.03)));
elif cadastro == 'G' or 'g' and quantidade >20 and tipo_comb == 'G' or 'g':
    print('você comprou {} litros, sem desconto seriam: {:.3f} reais \nO valor total com desconto é de {:.3f} reais'.format(
        quantidade, gasolina, (gasolina - gasolina * 0.05)));

#não clientes e alcool
if cadastro == 'C' or 'c' and quantidade <= 20 and tipo_comb == "A" or tipo_comb == "a":
    print('você comprou {} litros, sem desconto seriam: {:.3f} reais \nO valor total com desconto é de {:.3f} reais'.format(
            quantidade, alcool, (alcool - alcool* 0.03)));
elif cadastro == 'C' or 'c' and quantidade >20:
    print('você complor total com desconto é de {:.3rou {} litros, sem desconto seriam: {:.3f} reais \nO vaf} reais'.format(
            quantidade, alcool, (alcool - alcool * 0.05)));
```